# Which Open Source CMS do you find most reliable and performance-oriented?

Tags: content-management-system, cluster-computing

We need a good CMS that supports data clustering (managing and storing data on different servers). By "good" , I mean : reliable , minimum bugs , the faster the better. (Oh , and it should make coffee :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes … kitchen sink + community + support: Plone. Development heading very much in the right direction.

Plone is in some ways a different creature from many other systems. Depending on the environment, ultra-high performance may require some attention but in the community there's great expertise to steer any attention that may be required.

http://plone.org/support | Chat Room is a great venue for diverse and honest advice on this subject. We regularly steer people away from Plone -- when some other system will better suit their needs.

Answer (score 4):

If you want everything and the kitchen sink plus clustering/scaling support, I'd say [Plone](http://plone.org/). Very big community, written in Python, uses the Zope stack so it has a built in application server. Etc, etc. I suggest taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, and I think that you need to look for software to fit your need.  I have a few sites that only get minimal traffic that run on WordPress, but I also admin a site that runs Joomla and gets reliable amounts of traffic.

Also, Joomla has a wonderfully customizable interface with extensions, plugins, themes and a fairly easy to use administration tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about "Performance-oriented" means for you. There are sites with Drupal and Joomla that receives million of visits month after month, and do not need special configurations like data clustering.

I think you must ask yourself if you need all you said.

For reliability, and no bugs or minimum bugs i can stand for Joomla.

I think the performance is a function of the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to data clustering levels, your better off doing some real testing of CMS systems.

Most of the bigger names support a lot of things. 
MS CMS Server, DotnetNuke

Anything used by really large shops should work.